# Etymology of くだらない

Tags: translation, etymology

In the first episode of Death Note, the main character utters:

> まったくくだらねえ

which means

> Completely worthless

I'm assuming "くだらねえ" is the masculine-slang-negative of 下る, which means "to descend" or "to be inferior to".

**Question:** Since 下る already means "to be less than", why is this in the negative? Wouldn't that change the meaning of the sentence to be something like:

> Completely not-less-than

and hence reverse its meaning?

Comment: くだらない is an adjective, no idea if it actually comes from 下る but yeah it's its own word

Comment: FYI: https://gogen-yurai.jp/kudaranai/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

下る had an obsolete meaning "smoothly understood". Think of it like "digestible" in a figure of speech. 日本国語大辞典 says:

> (14)つかえないですらすらと進む。
> ＊正徹物語〔１４４８～５０頃〕下「詞つづきも哥めき、吟のくだりて理をつめず幽にもやさしくも有るがよき歌也」

下らない was originally the negation of this meaning: "hard to make sense", then "nonsense", then "worthless".

> たとえば、江戸時代の最初期に出た日本語・ポルトガル語の辞書『日葡【にっぽ】辞書』に、
> 〈この経の義がくだらぬ〔＝このお経の意味が分からない〕〉
> 　と記されています。つまり、「くだらぬ」は、「意味が分からない」という意味で、昔から使われていたのです。意味の分からないものは評価が低くなります。そこから今の「取るに足りない」という意味の「くだらない」につながるのです。 ([source](https://kangaeruhito.jp/article/3557))